# MVC pattern with JSF-Spring-MyBatis webapp

Tags: java, architecture, web-applications, mvc

I've a Java webapp with these frameworks and I want to know if my implementation meets with MVC pattern:

**Controller Layer (V)**

I'm using JSF

```
@ManagedBean
public class Controller{
    @ManagedProperty("#{business}")
    private Business business;

    public void insert(){
        business.insert();
    }
}
```

**Business Layer (C)**

I'm using Spring

```
public interface Business{
    public void insert();
}

@Service("business")
public class BusinessImpl implements Business{
    @Autowired
    private DaoMapper mapper;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insert(){
        mapper.insert();
    }
}
```

**Data Layer (M)**

I'm using MyBatis (This java interface is associated to XML file of MyBatis)

```
public interface DaoMapper{
    public void insert();
}
```

My layers implemented MVC pattern? I'm confused :S...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code specifically implementing MVC pattern then No but is it actually MVC, well that answer is **YES**.

As Bart van Ingen Schenau points out the data as well as behavior to retrieve the appropriate data are encompassed by the model.  This is correct but the important thing to remember about JSF is that the framework itself is inherently MVC.

### JSF Model

The managed bean and Spring injected business logic encapsulates the model.

### JSF View

Your XHTML markup represents the View components.  This markup also contains Controller hooks that bind your Model (Managed Beans, ORM entities, etc...) to the View components.

### JSF Controller

This is just FacesServlet.  It is the controller that creates the interaction between View and Model so that the web developer doesn't need to worry about this.

Comment: I already know that my webapp have two frameworks that implemented MVC pattern (JSF and Spring) apart MyBatis that's ORM. That's why I have doubt that as the MVC pattern applies to my webapp if I have two frameworks MVC. In my particular case my implmentation is so: **V** = > page XHTML and JSF Framework, **C** => Spring beans or only FacesServlet class?, **M**: Database, MyBatis and Spring beans?

Comment: @CesarCasasola Unless you are using Spring MVC then plain Spring is just a Dependency Injection framework and that has nothing to do with MVC.  Your controller is just FacesServlet.  Your model is all JSF Managed Beans, Spring Beans, business logic and MyBatis.  The model is where most of the interesting application stuff will exist anyway.

Comment: Oh, Ok. Everything is clearer :) and I supose that implementation layers is independent of MVC pattern? MVC pattern don't implied **only three layers**. Right?

Comment: @CesarCasasola `MVC pattern don't implied only three layers. Right?` I am not sure I understand sorry.  Your JSF implementation is automatically MVC because of the JSF framework.  Just like if you instead use Spring MVC your implementation is automatically MVC.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @CesarCasasola: MVC does not imply any layers at all. In typical depictions, MVC is shown as three circles arranged in a triangle, with arrows indicating the communication paths.

Answer (score 0):

No, your layers, as described, do *not* implement the MVC pattern.

Within the MVC pattern, the Model contains most of the application-specific logic, in particular the business logic and all the layers below it. So, in your three-layer structure, that would be both the Business and the Data layers.

The View contains the code for driving the the user interface. The View classes produce the HTML, JSON or XML that gets displayed by the browser.

The Controller classes tie it all together. They receive the requests from the browser, and instruct the Model and View to take the relevant actions based on that request.

Comment: Well...As you mention:                                                      **V** => XHTML files, JSF beans?                                        **C** => Class that managed Request. In my case should be FacesServlet class. It's ok?                                        **M** => All tables, procedures, function, etc of database

Comment: @CesarCasasola: Yes, that sounds more like it, but I am not familiar enough with the specific Java technology to tell for sure.